# defining a function of calculated values to whole dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I tried to apply a  average value calculation to whole dictionary of sets, but the df is returning columns with same value 1.0 instead of calculated values.

```
for a_dictionary,b_dictionary  in c_dictionary.items():

    def x_property(value_dict):
        return g_x(value_dict,b_dictionary)

    df["average_of_"+a] = df["total_dict"].map(x_property)
```

The value of g_x is calculated from values obtained from similar function as shown above.There it did work, but in the next case, it is not giving values.

I get no error but the value is returning as constant 1.0 instead of a calculated value in each row of the columns of dictionary of df.

Comment: why do you define function inside loop?

Comment: as temporary function to assign the values of calculated g_x  to x_property and then map x_property to the total_dict.

Comment: That *could* be a case of https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures, but regardless the coding pattern is totally weird. Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with expected and actual output?